# Template to determine the size in bytes of various variables

Tags: c++, size, c++14

I need a universal way of determining the memory size of a currently allocated contiguous variable without the need to create tons of templates for each one of the types. I mostly need this template function for C++ style containers, but (because I don't know the Type in advance) I need it to be also compatible with primitive C types.

Edited the question to sound a little bit more descriptive and pedantic.

Comment: stackoverflow.com is not a code-writing service. You need to try to writing such a template yourself, first, then explain why it is not working the way you expect it to work, and how you expect it to work.

Comment: "C++ types don't allways works with *sizeof()*" -- what?! "Classic C types"?! "Contiguous types"???

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Well, I don't even know where to start. All I can think of is a stupid load of templates for each of the types.

Comment: `sizeof` works just fine with C++ types.

Comment: Right. That's how you would do that. Looks like you know exactly how to write such a template.

Comment: @PeteBecker sizeof will most of the time return the container implementation.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I think Brian has a better idea than both of us.

Comment: @areuz -- yes, that's what `sizeof` does: it gives you the size of the object. If you want to do something else you need to say what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution in C++14, assuming I understood what you meant:

```
template <class Container>
constexpr auto byte_size(const Container& container) {
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    return (end(container) - begin(container)) * sizeof(container[0]);
}
```

Note that this will work even if the container is empty, since `sizeof` does not evaluate its operand.

It won't work for `std::vector<bool>` though---guess you'll have to add a specialization for that.

Comment: Wouldn't that give completely nonsensical answers for things like lists, maps, sets, deques...?

Comment: Good start, but this 'std::size' is only available in C++17 according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size. My `‘size’ is not a member of ‘std’` compilation error just confirms it. While including the <iterator> header.

Comment: @areuz sorry, will fix

Comment: So far it seems like it works (except for primitive types like `int`, etc.) but I'll be able to deal with that :), and why do you think It won't work with `std::vector<bool>` types?

Comment: @areuz `operator[]` returns a proxy type for `std::vector<bool>`. I guess what you'll have to do is just divide the container size by `CHAR_BIT` to guess the true number of bytes allocated.

Comment: @Brian: vectors don't really work like that. You can't easily know the amount of allocated memory from just the element size.

Comment: @KerrekSB I know that, so I interpreted the question in a way that made it possible to answer.